# Implications of Hibernate/JPA caching on multi-node architecture

Tags: hibernate, jpa

What are the implications of using Hibernate/JPA in a horizontally-scalable architecture? Specifically, I am talking about the fact that Hibernate has a first-level cache which is always on. And there may be many copies of the application running at the same time. So a load balancer may direct web service requests to different application instances.

In my SpringBoot application

- I am mixing JPQL and native SQL queries
- Using default flush mode AUTO flush mode by default
- Using optimistic locking on some entities with @Version annotation

Are there any cases where there may be consistency issues?

Are there any Hibernate flags that should be turned on for these types of scenarios? (for example ALWAYS flush mode)?